# Logstash fingerprint filter not working

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash filter that extracts an api token string from an XML payload. I don't want to store the actual API token in elasticsearch, I want to store a hashed version. My filter file is as follows:

```
filter {

    xml {
        source => "xml_request"
        store_xml => "false"
        force_array => "false"
        xpath => [ "//authentication/apiKey/text()", "api_key" ]
    }

    if [api_key] =~ /.+/ {
        fingerprint {
            method => "SHA256"
            key => "some_random_string"
            source => "api_key"
            target => "api_key"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the fingerprint filter does not seem to be working because the `api_key` value is always the value from the XML input and not SHA256 hashed. I have tried setting the `target` field to a new field (e.g. `api_key_hashed`) to test, but the new field does not show up. Can anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this helps, but you can try:

```
  fingerprint {
    add_field => {
      "apikey" => "%{api_key}"
       remove_field => [ "%{api_key}" ]
    }
    add_field => {
      "api_key" => "%{apikey}"
      remove_field => [ "%{apikey}" ]
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, you can try:
[GROK_OVERRIDE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-overwrite) or [GROK ADD FIELD](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_field) or [DROP ADD FIELD](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html#plugins-filters-drop-add_field)